# Liquibase gradle plugin not working Spring Boot SQL server

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, liquibase, gradle-plugin

I am trying to use Liquibase Gradle plugin in Spring Boot for SQL server but plugin is doing nothing. It is not throwing error or doing anything. However, when I run Spring Boot application I see that it runs the migration but I need rollback feature as well.
Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.0.2'
}

group = 'com.test.tango'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Here is my `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL:jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=tango}
spring.liquibase.user=${DB_USERNAME:sa}
spring.liquibase.password=${DB_PASSWORD:password}
spring.liquibase.liquibase-schema=tango
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/master-changelog.xml
```

I tried to follow https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin but I do not want to redefine creds there, more over example is for MySQL. Can I do this for MSSQL server.

Comment: I had the same issue. did you able to solve this?